# Put dot in brief description

Tags: doxygen

I got this sample code. I want a dot in my brief comment.

```cpp
const int myVar = 1;   //!< Doxygen very long brief\.
                       //!  Brief sentence two.
```

I escape the dot as told in the doxygen manual.
This does not work. The first line is brief, the second is detailed. Is this a bug?

Note: `MULTILINE_CPP_IS_BRIEF` and `QT_AUTOBRIEF` is `YES`! I use the latest version (1.8.9.1).

Comment: I think the newline may be significant. What happens if you use only one line?

Comment: It gives the same output.

Comment: The problem also appears for "i.e." and "e.g.", so this is a real issue. A possible solution to this, however, would be \ie and \eg, which right now do not exist, afaik.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [doxygen manual](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/docblocks.html) says

> If you enable this option and want to put a dot in the middle of a sentence without ending it, you should put a backslash and a space after it.

Your backslash ist on the wrong side of the dot, and the manual has to be taken literally, meaning the space is required after the backslash.

The following should work (without the curly braced part):

```cpp
const int myVar = 1;   //!< Doxygen very long brief.\ {← SPACE here!}
                       //!  Brief sentence two.
```

Answer (score 1):

Then I think you must be explicit and use the `\brief` command. The doxygen documentation [Documenting the code](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/docblocks.html) says

> For the brief description there are also several possibilities:
>
> 1.One could use the \brief command with one of the above comment blocks. This command ends at the end of a paragraph, so the detailed description follows after an empty line.
>
> Here is an example:
>
> `/*! \brief Brief description.
>    *         Brief description continued.
>    *
>    *  Detailed description starts here.
>    */`

You may also need to set `JAVADOC_AUTOBRIEF` to NO. If you still have problems, see if you get what you are looking for by putting the comment before rather than after `myVar`.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Hi Phil, i cannot disable autobrief. Also, a `//!<`Comment is always Brief. Adding brief does not help. You suggestion to put it bevor the variable works, but this messes up the style of the files. I really guess this is a bug :(

Answer (score 0):

The backslash appears to be on the wrong side. Here is an additional example of the correct way to do it:

```cpp
const int myInt = 2;   //!< Brief description (e.g.\ using only a few words). Details follow.
```